# PHP Session Variable disappears after page refresh

Tags: php, session, variables

I have a big problem and i cant solve it. My session variables are exchanged between files but after refresh of the second page they disappear.

Here's the code:

**index.php**

```
session_start();

header('Title: So random');
header('charset: UTF-8');

//if index.php?login is requested
if(isset($_REQUEST['login'])) {

    //'pass' input box value (from POST) is saved to $pass variable.
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    //if pasword matches Password.
    if($pass == 'Password') {

        //session_start();

        $_SESSION['logintoken'] = "approoved";
        header("Location: list.php");
        die();

    } else { $error = true; }

}

if(isset($_SESSION['logintoken'])) { 
        header('Location: list.php'); 
        die();
    }


?>
Random HTML With login page goes here...
```

And then we have page, which is availble only for logged in. After redirecting from login to it it's okay but after refresh i have "logintoken not defined".

**list.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['logintoken'] != "approoved") { 
    //'<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; url=index.php">'
    die();
}

?>
<html> goes here....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Title: So random');
header('charset: UTF-8');   
$_SESSION['logintoken']='' ;
```

EDIT:
perhaps this is better

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logintoken']) && ($_SESSION['logintoken'] != "approoved"))
```

EDIT 2:

```
    header("Location: list.php?token=".$_SESSION['logintoken']);
```

list.php

```
if($_REQUEST['token'] != "approoved") { 
    //'<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0; url=index.php">'
    die();
}
```

Comment: That would make no sense (the second one) cause firstly check if it set